# Fixing \foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I use the following code, I get a semicolon between the drawings. How can I fix this!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
{
\newcommand\partFillRec[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (1,1);
\draw[very thick, draw=red, fill=yellow!40] (a) rectangle (b);
\draw[draw=none, fill=red] (a) rectangle ($(a-|b)!#1!(b)$);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\foreach \x in {0,.2,...,1} \partFillRec{\x};
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Technically, the body of each loop needs to be in `{}`. However, if no `{` is found, it grabs everything up to the `;` which – when used *inside* TikZ – should be one path command. This `;` is inserted again, since every path needs to finish with a `;`. Since you don't use it inside a TikZ diagram and `;` isn't part of the `\partFillRec` macro,  the `;` just shows up after the TikZ picture you do create with your macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the code argument of `\foreach` in `{…}` instead of terminating it with semicolon:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\partFillRec[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (1,1);
    \draw[very thick, draw=red, fill=yellow!40] (a) rectangle (b);
    \draw[draw=none, fill=red] (a) rectangle ($(a-|b)!#1!(b)$);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {0,.2,...,1} {\partFillRec{\x}}
\end{document}
```

[image: no semicolon or space between the images]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to add that it is better to add a space in the code to become  \foreach \x in {0,.1,...,1} {\partFillRec{\x} } to separate the rectangles.

Comment: @Hany If you want a space, add a space. But in your question you've only asked for removing the semicolon. So I didn't know, that you want a space instead of the semicolon.

Comment: @– cabohah ok, I did not know that removing the semicolon will result in sticking the rectangles together. So, thank you again.

Comment: @Hany to put a space bewween square change the loop this way:
'\foreach \x in {0,.2,...,1} {\partFillRec{\x}\;}'

Comment: @– Raffaele Santoro Thank you. Is there a way to separated the rectangles other than adding a space!

Comment: @Hany What kind of separation do you want? You could, e.g., add a black vertical line of every width you want. Or you could use every horizontal distance you want. Just use whatever you want and if you are not successful just ask a question.

Comment: @– cabohah  Thank you for your addition

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is for this result:

[image]

The line to change is:

```
\foreach \x in {0,.2,...,1} {\partFillRec{\x}\;}
```

If You want more space:

[image]

consider the use of \hspace{.5cm} or higer:

```
\foreach \x in {0,.2,...,1} {\partFillRec{\x}\hspace{.5cm}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your addition